# Git clone over an existing non-git project

Tags: git, deployment, git-clone

Here's the thing. I have an old php app that run on a server.  I copied the php file to my computer and made git with it. (git init and push to our git server)  Now comes the tricky part, the server cannot git push (only pull with deploy key), but the file are still on the server. I added some modification to my git repo (some quick fix) and would like to apply them to my non-git php apps.

Is this possible ?

I was thinking about git init, add on the server and then add a remote and pull, but i'm pretty sure it will juste conflict every file.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `git init` on the server and then add, commit then create a branch different from the branch you want to check out from the repo just for backup, then you check out the branch you want it should be fine.

So on the server:

```
cd /path/to/repository
git init
git checkout -b server-backup
git add -a # or something more precise to ignore what needs to be ignored, etc.
git commit -m 'Backup commit from server'
git branch -D master
git remote add origin user@central.repo:project
git fetch origin
git push -u origin server-backup
# *
git checkout branch-you-want-to-deploy
```

* To be very safe, before the last step, probably you want to fetch on your box and verify that the difference between the server-backup and your branch is what you really want to deploy.

```
# on client
git fetch origin
git diff server-backup..branch-you-want-to-deploy
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't how this won't works. Good idea ! :P